# how to copy/paste a formula in Excel absolutely?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I copy/paste a formula in Microsoft Excel so that the exact formula, verbatim, is copied and pasted?  That is, I don't want it to increment or use other logic to [interpret](https://www.wikihow.com/Copy-Formulas-in-Excel) how I want the pasted formula modified.  I don't want the references updated or modified.

Comment: Method 3 (copying a formula exactly) from your link seems to do exactly what you need. Have you tried it? (also tried "alternate methods"?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Select the cell containing the formula

2) Highlight the formula's text in the Formula bar

[image]

3) Copy (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)

4) Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>

5) Select the cell where you want to paste the formula

6) Paste (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to write your formulas with direct references.  Use $A$1 rather than A1.  Or $A1 if you want only the number to increment but the column to stay the same, or vice versa (A$1).